# how can i add filter widget in tkiter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

hi~ i use tkinter in python gui. my code is listbox wdiget. i want add filter with listbox widget.
but i don't know make it not at all. how can i to do for make that.
i want to add filter.. i don't know make like that.. 
help me please.  i dont know make search_data().

```
from tkinter import *

def search_data():
    print('d')


root=Tk()
dd = Frame(root, borderwidth=0 )
# create the entry widget
entry_value = StringVar()
entry = Entry(dd, textvariable=entry_value)
entry.pack(side=LEFT) # where ever you want it
Button(dd, text = 'search ', command = search_data).pack(side=LEFT)    
dd.pack()

scrollbar=Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y) 
mylist=Listbox(root,yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,  width=100, height=15)
for line in range(100):
    mylist.insert(END,"This is line number " + str(line))
mylist.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH) 
scrollbar.config(command=mylist.yview)     
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a filter, you need to have "something" in your GUI for your user to enter the filter pattern.

e.g. an `Entry` widget as we are talking tkinter.

**Pseudo code**

```
# do your imports

# create the entry widget
entry_value = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=entry_value)
entry.pack() # where ever you want it

#now add your list box

#add e.g. a button to apply your filter

def filter_data():
    # ... iterate over your data, check if your filter applies and decide how to proceed
```

for the button: check callbacks and datastructures from the docs to see how this could be done.

Storing of data:

You are adding items directly to the list.

`mylist.insert(END,"This is line number " + str(line))`

This is a way of displaying the data - Yes.
Is this maintainable code? Not really.

To filter data displayed, I do recommend some `refresh` function that accesses the stored data to display.

How to achieve this?
Normally there should be some sort of array, dict or something similar to store the data in. Could also be a file where you read and parse the data.

Let me give you an example based on your code:

- You have a dummy generator `for i in range(0,100):`

  I suppose you will later on read a file based on the naming of your variables, but changed it to commonly used `i` used as an index in most common loops.

  In your code, you could store the data in a list.

```
raw_data = range(0,100)
actual_data = raw_data # this will be used from now on inside your refresh
def refresh():
    # clean your listbox

    # iterate over the data
    for line in actual_data:
        #add it now to the listbox

def filter():
    # get your filter pattern first
    # we have a string var, so use "get()"
    filter_pattern = entry_value.get()
    # now create a new list
    actual_data = []
 
    # iterate over raw data, check if data matches filter
    # if it does, append it to actual_data

    # call refresh now
    refresh()
```

**Yes, I do know that there is a lot missing in that code example. I left the implementation of the missing parts to the reader.**